# Pandas sets datetime to first day of month if missing day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When I used Pandas to convert my datetime string, it sets it to the first day of the month if the day is missing.

For example:

```
   pd.to_datetime('2017-06')

   OUT[]: Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:00:00')
```

Is there a way to have it use the 15th (middle) day of the month?

EDIT:

I only want it to use day 15 if the day is missing, otherwise use the actual date - so offsetting all values by 15 won't work.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('2017-06') + pd.to_timedelta(14, unit='d')`?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with sample data? If you have a mix of formats this can be more difficult than a simple constant offset. Or is it just one string?

Comment: Do you want to convert all dates regardles if it has a day or not to 15 or only when missing?

Comment: You only have dates with either the 'YYYY-MM' or 'YYYY-MM-DD' format?

Comment: I'd say modify the string before pd.to_datetime.  So, add '-15' where the day doesn't exists in the string.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't possible using the actual call, you could always use regex matching to figure out if the string contains a date and proceed accordingly. Note: this code only works if using '-' delimited dates:

```
import re
date_str = '2017-06'
if (not bool(re.match('.+-.+-.+',date_str))):
    pd.to_datetime(date_str).replace(date=15)
else:
    pd.to_datetime(date_str)
```